# How to change HTML codes to symbols iphone

Tags: iphone, html, ios, symbols

I have written a function that changes texts like "`&rsaquo;`", "`&laquo;`" to symbols "›" "«" and I want to share this function with stackoverflow users. If you have suggestions how to make this function better please write !!! Thank you !!!

```
- (NSString*) ChangeAccentsLettersToSymbols: (NSString*) strToCorrect {
    NSLog(@"ChangeAccentsLettersToSymbols Entered\n");
    static NSString * const codeMap[][2] = {
        {@"&iexcl;",    @"¡"},  {@"&laquo;",    @"«"},  {@"&raquo;",    @"»"},  {@"&lsaquo;",   @"‹"},  
        {@"&rsaquo;",   @"›"},  {@"&sbquo;",    @"‚"},  {@"&bdquo;",    @"„"},  {@"&ldquo;",    @"“"},  
        {@"&rdquo;",    @"”"},  {@"&lsquo;",    @"‘"},  {@"&rsquo;",    @"’"},  {@"&cent;",     @"¢"},
        {@"&pound;",    @"£"},  {@"&yen;",      @"¥"},  {@"&euro;",     @"€"},  {@"&curren;",   @"¤"},  
        {@"&fnof;",     @"ƒ"},  {@"&gt;",       @">"},  {@"&lt;",       @"<"},  {@"&divide;",   @"÷"},  
        {@"&deg;",      @"°"},  {@"&not;",      @"¬"},  {@"&plusmn;",   @"±"},  {@"&micro;",    @"µ"},
        {@"&amp;",      @"&"},  {@"&reg;",      @"®"},  {@"&copy;",     @"©"},  {@"&trade;",    @"™"},  
        {@"&bull;",     @"•"},  {@"&middot;",   @"·"},  {@"&sect;",     @"§"},  {@"&ndash;",    @"–"},  
        {@"&mdash;",    @"—"},  {@"&dagger;",   @"†"},  {@"&Dagger;",   @"‡"},  {@"&loz;",      @"◊"},
        {@"&uarr;",     @"↑"},  {@"&darr;",     @"↓"},  {@"&larr;",     @"←"},  {@"&rarr;",     @"→"},  
        {@"&harr;",     @"↔"},  {@"&iquest;",   @"¿"},  {@"&nbsp;",     @" "},  {@"&quot;",     @"\""}
    };
    int count = sizeof(codeMap)/sizeof(codeMap[0]);
    for( int i=0; i<count; ++i ) {
        strToCorrect = [ strToCorrect stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: codeMap[i][0] 
                                                                withString: codeMap[i][1] ];
    }

    for( int i=33; i<126; ++i) {
        NSString* whotToReplace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&#%d;", i];
        NSString* replaceWith   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", (char*)i ];
        strToCorrect = [strToCorrect stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: whotToReplace
                                                               withString: replaceWith ];
    }
    return strToCorrect;
}
```

Comment: you could have used NSDictionary instead of the array?

Comment: First, method names in Objective-C start with a lowercase character by convention, just like in any other programming language (except for Visual BASIC, AFAIK). Then you want to lowercase "&Dagger;". Next, the `&#xxx;` notation can be used to represent any UTF character, from 0 up to 65535 (AFAIK) but you only cover a few of them and don't handle octal or hex. So in all, this method can indeed be handy but one needs to be aware that it isn't complete and also quite inefficient due to calling `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` a dozen times. So don't use it on long texts.

Comment: stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: And whot can I do ?

Comment: @Syed Absar: No, because his C array is static which means it will be generated at *compile time* and is simply mapped into memory along with the rest of the static data. It's also the most efficient for iterating. Using an NSDictionary would be quite inefficient and also a lot more writing.

Comment: @ViTo Brother: The most efficient way would be to implement a simple parser with a state machine. A lot more work, of course, but way more efficient. For short HTML files your solution is acceptable, but I wouldn't throw a 100kB file at it :-)

Comment: "implement a simple parser with a state machine" Sorry what do you mean ??? Can you explain ?

Comment: I just used your method and it's working for special charachters like &bull; when stringByDecodingHTMLEntities doesn't. There is just a small error in your code, you don't want to use a char* but a simple char in your string with format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is repo on github -

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

look at this functions

```
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
- (NSString *)stringByEncodingHTMLEntities;
```

its working fine for me.